# sdm package fails in shiny io

Tags: r, shiny, package

I'm have built a couple of species distribution models using `sdm:sdm()` From these I make predictions using `raster::predict()` and `sdm::ensemble()` based on widget input data in a shiny app. (Note that `raster::predict()` also loads the sdm package automatically if it detects a sdm object). The application works locally, but not on the server shiny.io.

I have stripped he server.R script down and added one element at the time until the error occurs, and that seems to be when either of these functions are run. The error log return

> Warning: Error in <-: replacement has length zero

If I move the predict/ensemble function outside of the renderPlot() part of server.R it also returns:

> Error in m[i] <- .self$whichMethod(m[i]) : replacement has length zero

I have traced this error to [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/sdm/src/R/AAAClasses.R) but have not found anything that indicates why the app should work locally and not on the server. I tried removing all mentions of maxent models as this requires a modification of the local library by adding a maxent.jar file to the dismo/java/ folder. This did not affect anything. I have also updated all essential packages and redeployed.

The shiny script as pasted below and you'll find additional needed files [here](https://github.com/anders-kolstad/sdmShiny/blob/master/shiny/sdmModels/Kobresia_new.sdm) [here](https://github.com/anders-kolstad/sdmShiny/blob/master/shiny/IVapp.grd) and [here](https://github.com/anders-kolstad/sdmShiny/blob/master/shiny/IVapp.gri).

```
library(shiny)
library(sdm)
library(raster)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("This is my app"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("Example sidebar")
    ),

    mainPanel("Plots", 
                 plotOutput("map")
                 )
    )
  ))

# import raster stack- IVapp.grd and IVapp.gri should be in the same folder ass app.R
IV      <- raster::stack("IVapp.grd")

# import sdm model object
m       <- read.sdm("Kobresia_new.sdm")

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$map <- renderPlot({
      withProgress(message = 
                     "Working on it ... please wait" , value = 0, {

      # make predictions from sdm 
      pred    <- raster::predict(m, IV, 
                         mean=TRUE,
                         filename = "predicted.img",
                         overwrite=TRUE)
                     })
      plot(pred)
      }) #renderPlot
    } 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This app works locally, but not on [shinyapps.io](https://anderskolstad.shinyapps.io/sdmShinyTestApp/).

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.6.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.6.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8          LC_NUMERIC=C                  LC_TIME=nb_NO.UTF-8          
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8        LC_MONETARY=nb_NO.UTF-8       LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8      
 [7] LC_PAPER=nb_NO.UTF-8          LC_NAME=nb_NO.UTF-8           LC_ADDRESS=nb_NO.UTF-8       
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=nb_NO.UTF-8      LC_MEASUREMENT=nb_NO.UTF-8    LC_IDENTIFICATION=nb_NO.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] sdm_1.0-89          ggplot2_3.2.1       kernlab_0.9-29      rpart_4.1-15        randomForest_4.6-14
 [6] RSNNS_0.4-12        Rcpp_1.0.4.6        rJava_0.9-12        earth_5.1.2         plotmo_3.5.6       
[11] TeachingDemos_2.10  plotrix_3.7-7       Formula_1.2-3       glmnet_3.0-2        Matrix_1.2-17      
[16] mgcv_1.8-28         nlme_3.1-141        mda_0.4-10          class_7.3-15        tree_1.0-40        
[21] gbm_2.1.5           dismo_1.1-4         rgdal_1.4-8         gridExtra_2.3       rasterVis_0.47     
[26] latticeExtra_0.6-29 lattice_0.20-38     raster_3.1-5        sp_1.4-1            shiny_1.4.0.2      
[31] dplyr_0.8.3
```

Can someone help shed some light on this?
Kind regards,
Anders Kolstad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

library(sdm) doesn't, like the other packages, tell the virtuell server to install it's dependencies. This package relies on a command sdm::install_all() for this. This command doesn't work in shiny, but did this instead:

Start a new R session (sdm unattached)

library(sdm)

Then do something like predict(myModel, ...)

This causes R to load all dependencies, which are then printed in the console. I added these to the top of the server.R file:

```
library(shiny)
library(sdm)
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(dismo)
library(gbm)
#library(tree)
library(mda)
library(class)
library(mgcv)
library(nlme)
library(glmnet)
library(Matrix)
library(earth)
library(Formula)
library(plotrix)
library(TeachingDemos)
library(rJava)
library(RSNNS)
library(Rcpp)
library(randomForest)
library(rpart)
library(kernlab)
library(rasterVis)
library(gridExtra)
library(rgdal)
library(shinyjs)
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)
```

You can hash out those you don't need, but I'm not sure how to be sure which ones you do need.

This now work on shinyapps.io. (Note that the example shiny is not updated with this solution. )

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace raster::predict with sdm::predict because sdm has its own predict function. I hope this fixes the issue.

Best regards,
Babak

Comment: Thank you Babak. I did try this, but get this error: ```Error: 'predict' is not an exported object from 'namespace:sdm'
```

Comment: What about using predict alone (without raster::   or sdm::)?

Comment: -fails on the server, but work similar to raster::predict locally. But note that the solution to the specific problem of this post is solved above. Cheers.